# How to import python files within two subdirectories

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a directory structure as below

```
 - src\module1\ __init__.py 
 - src\module1\foo1.py 
 - src\module2\ __init__.py
 - src\module2\foo2.py
```

I want to import functions from foo1.py in foo2.py. I tried importing using

```
from module1.foo1 import *
```

but this is throwing traceback error.
please suggest how to import `foo1.py` in `foo2.py`

Thanks in advance
manu

Comment: `src` must be in `sys.path` to allow the import you desire.  Is it?

Comment: Please paste the error message into your question (inside a code block).

Comment: Presumably you are seeing an `ImportError` exception? It helps if you can at least report the error message, if no the whole traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from module1.foo1 import ClassName
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

> 6.1.2. The Module Search Path
>
> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
>
> PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the
>   shell variable PATH).
>
> the installation-dependent default.
>
> After initialization, Python programs can modify sys.path.

So let's modify sys.path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('src\module1\')
import foo1
```

It's worth printing sys.path so you can see why it's not being found already.

Comment: I don't want to change the system path